# Using .each To Show Element In One Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table inside a foreach. I want on keyup to show a button in that specific table. Here is my code.
(submitEditedTimes is the button)

```
 $(".editable").on('keyup', function () {

            $(".submitEditedTimes").each(function () {
                $(this).show();
            })
        })
```

Here is the table

```
<table class="table table-user-information">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Finish Time</td>
                            <td> <input type="text" contenteditable="true"  class="editable" value="@k.timeUntil.ToShortTimeString()" style="border: none" /></td>
                        </tr>


                <tr class="submitEditedTimes">
                    <td></td>
                    <td><label class="btn btn-danger col-xs-6">Submit</label></td>
                </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Why is this up voted within a second after it was posted when it doesn't include the relevant code for anyone to be able to help? And, there is nothing particularly "up votable" about the question in general?

Comment: what have you done, what is the actual issue(error?) that piece of code doesnt help need more, outline is insufficient

Comment: `$(this).show();`

Comment: thanks @Alon I fixed that. Now it is showing the button in all tables? How do I show the button in the specific table that was edited?

Comment: @N.Sch Put this in the  `'keyup'` callback, replace it with what you have now `$(this).parents('table').find(".submitEditedTimes").show()`

Comment: hmm tried that. It is still showing the button on all tables?

Comment: `.parent`, not `parents`

Comment: Oh, thanks @ScottMarcus - But doesn't it go up one parent?

Comment: Got it it is working! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Actually parents works not parent?

Comment: @N.Sch Can you please tell us what worked for you? :)

Comment: What you originally wrote. When I said it didn't work I didn't realize I had to take out the .each. so htis works                                 $(".editable").on('keyup', function () {
        $(this).parents('table').find(".submitEditedTimes").show()
    });

Comment: @N.Sch Good to know, and thank you